# Microsoft Power Platform Custom Connector to Project Server API - OAuth 2.0 Settings

Tags: oauth-2.0, powerapps, power-automate, project-online, ms-project-server-2016

When building a custom connector from powerapps/powerautomate to the Project Server API where can I find out what the OAuth settings should be? Settings include:

- Identity Provider
- Client id
- Client secret
- Login URL
- Tenant ID
- Resource URL
- Scope
- Redirect URL

I have full admin rights to SharePoint, project online, and Azure-AD; I just don't know what those mean or where to find them and an hour of googling has me no closer to the answer. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is this resolved? Any follow up questions?

Comment: I can't figure it out. I've spent hours on this at different times over the last year and I get the feeling it will take days or weeks that I don't have.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `OAuth 2.0` and for that you have to finish "App registration" in Azure Active Directory (AAD). Once registered, you will get the necessary details - Application Id (Client id), Key (Client secret), URLs, etc.

[Read more: Use Azure Active Directory with a custom connector in Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/azure-active-directory-authentication)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since Project (assuming Microsoft Project) is authenticated through Active Directory for your org, you may also be able to use "basic authentication" in your Custom Connector.

If I'm not mistaken, PowerApps will handle the creation and passing of a Bearer Token for Microsoft apps such as Project.

Its worth a try as sometimes the admins for AD are faaaaar away and creating an app ID as mentioned above is infeasible.